# Is the Server Collation Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS required for Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, project-server

In a Project Server 2010 farm. Is it required that SQL Server has the Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS server collation? The software are:

Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise
SharePoint 2010 Enterprise
Project Server
SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard

In the SQL Server setup that collation is missing. Can I used another server collation instead and continue with my farm without future problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are running 
Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise
SharePoint 2010 Enterprise
Project 2010
SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

and we are using the collation

Latin1_General_CI_AS

without any problems at all, so guess it doesn't really matter that much to the software.

Answer (score 1):

This [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288970.aspx#section1) talks about SQL Server collation for SharePoint databases.

The information in this [MicroSoft Learn](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2008668) link states that the "SQL Server collation must be configured to be case-insensitive, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, Kana-sensitive, and width-sensitive. This is to ensure file name uniqueness is consistent with the Windows operating system."

"However, we do not support changing the default collation (Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS) for SharePoint databases to any other collations (CI, AS, KS, WS)."

"We support any CI collation for the SQL instance (for master, tempdb databases). However we recommend using Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS as the instance default collation (master, tempdb databases)."

Further information can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130075245/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1e7fcf0-3c20-47b1-af5e-8a6577e5f88e/sharepoint-sql-collation-best-practice?forum=sharepointadminprevious).